# Transforming a table into matrix in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

So I basically have something like the situation in the picture where I need to transform the table in A into a matrix like in B. The row/column headers are not necessary, just the Matrix. I would be open to a tool other than Excel if it would be simpler, like Matlab,SQL,Python or R. Is it possible to do this in a straight forward manner for a large amount of rows (several thousand)

[image]

Comment: Use a Pivot Table

Comment: Can you expand on how you would do that? Putting the transaction amount on the columns tab just gives me their sum

Answer (score 2):

[image]

**How it works:**

- Select Source data `S28:U37`.
- From **I**nsert TAB hit **P**ivot Table.
- Better create PT in Existing Sheet.
- Use Company, Transaction Amount & Row Number in ROWS, VALUES & in COLUMNS (Check attached screen shot).
- Now select any cell of Pivot Table then from **D**esign TAB, click **G**rand Totals, and hit **O**n For Column Only.

**N.B.**

- *You may adjust Grand Totals as your need.*
- *Grand Totals for Columns has been added, since you have asked for, through comments above.*

---

- Once again select PT and **R**ight click.
- Now from Popup menu hit **P**ivot Table Options.

[image]

---

Now from the displayed dialogue box hit TAB **D**isplay, then un-check **D**isplay Field Captions and Filter drop downs.

[image]

- Finish with **O**k.

---

**Note:**

- If you don't need the Grand Totals, reset the settings for `Off for Rows and Columns`, you get the result as shown below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you have Excel 2010+, you can use `Power Query` also known as `Get&Transform`

- `Data Tab` → `Get & Transform` → `From Table/Range`
- Select the `Row nr` column and Pivot Column

  - Values Column:= `Transaction Amount`
  - Advanced Options:  `Don't Aggregate`

[image]

#### M-Code

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Company", type text}, {"Transaction amount", Int64.Type}, {"Row nr", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Changed Type", {{"Row nr", type text}}, "en-US"), List.Distinct(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Changed Type", {{"Row nr", type text}}, "en-US")[#"Row nr"]), "Row nr", "Transaction amount"),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Pivoted Column",{{"Company", "Company/Row"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns"
```

**Results**

[image]